# PHP with gitlab bundled nginx not working

Tags: php, nginx, gitlab-omnibus

I've setup gitlab using the omnibus package on CentOS 7. I'd like to use the gitlab server to host additional websites. I've enabled custom nginx conf by adding the below code to /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb

```
nginx['custom_nginx_config'] = "include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;"
```

I've also created conf files in /etc/nginc/conf.d. Static HTML files are working but when i try to run php scripts, I'm getting a File not found - 404 error.

Following is the nginx conf for php :

```
server{
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/example;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    error_page 404 /404.html;
    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root /opt/gitlab/embedded/html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

    }

}
```

The following is the error log:

> FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response from upstream, client x.x.x.x, server: example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upsteam: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com"

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your problem comes from your "location ~ .php$" config.

You already fix the first problem with gitlab omnibus by included the right fatscgi_params instead of the default. Now it seems to comes from the location config.

Try the following code for your configuration :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
   #in your case maybe : /opt/gitlab/embedded/html
   root  [YOUR APP DIRECTORY]; 

   try_files  $uri  $uri/  /index.php?$args;
   index  index.html index.htm index.php;

   fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
   fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

   fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
   fastcgi_index index.php;
   fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   fastcgi_intercept_errors on;

   include /opt/gitlab/embedded/conf/fastcgi_params;
}
```

This fix works for me on a Debian 8 server.

Hope it could help.